# Return result of VersionCheck.getLatestVersion() as string

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to output the version number of my app using react-native-version-check, am I missing something here? Console logging latestVersion works but not this.

```
renderAppVersion = () => {
    VersionCheck.getLatestVersion({
        provider: 'appStore'
    })
    .then(latestVersion => {
        return latestVersion;
    });
}


<Text>App Version: {this.renderAppVersion()}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

VersionCheck.getLatestVersion is an Async function so you wont get value when you use this.renderAppVersion() because it is also an Async function use state for storing the version which got from function and render it

code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [version, setVersion] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    VersionCheck.getLatestVersion().then(v => setVersion(v))
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
     {version && <Text>{version}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you point me in a direction where I'm not using Hooks? Need to adhere to the old version in this case.

Comment: are you using class component